# Help to define sigma-additivity on probability function over natrual numbers

Tags: probability

Let $(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}}, P)$ be a probability space, with $P({1})=t$, $P(2)=1-t$, with $t\in \mathbb{R}, 0\leq t\leq 1$, and for $n > 2$ let $P(n) = 0$. I'm trying to prove P holds sigma additivity: for $A_1,\ldots,A_n,\ldots$ pairwise disjoint events in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, one has $P(\dot{\bigcup}_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_i)$. I can't see how to do it, since it really depends whether $\dot{\bigcup}_{n=1}^{\infty}A_i$ contains the numbers 1 and 2 or not. How do I prove it?

Edit: I understand I can simply break it into four simple cases. But I've been trying to find a more general proof, in case I need to define $P$ over $m$ natural numbers.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli that's certainly correct, I was hoping for something more elegant (and that can possibly be expanded for more than just two numbers defined)

Comment: You can use pairwise disjointness to break it into very simple cases.